# Why it is not work if putting \t in resource string

Tags: c#, console

I have a console application, added a resource file (.resx) in the project, and I added a string like this:

```
**Name**                        **Value**

ArgInvalid            The arguments are invalid...

                      \t/a\t\tShow all the result.
```

Then in the program, I wrote `Console.WriteLine(Resource.ArgInvalid);`

but what it shows is *\t/a\t\tShow all the result*. What I want is that \t should be treated as tab, so how to make it print string as following:

```
      /a                      Show all the result.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is answered in: [tabbing in C# resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907150/tabbing-in-c-resource-file)

Enter the tab character in your resource file rather than \t - \t is something interpretted by C#, but not all languages.

If you really want to leave \t in your resource file, then you'll have to do:

```
Console.WriteLine(Resource.ArgInvalid.Replace("\\t", "\t")
```

This will replace the \t characters in the resource string with actual tab characters.

Comment: +1 - resource files are language independent. "\t" is a C# specific escape sequence.